# pisa django displaying chinese characters as black blocks

Tags: python, django, encoding, cjk, reportlab

I am trying to display Chinese characters using reportlab pisa. The generated Chinese words become black blocks. I am using UTF-8 to generate the PDFs

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
    """Function to render html template into a pdf file"""
    template = get_template(template_src)
    context = Context(context_dict)
    html  = template.render(context)
    result = StringIO.StringIO()

    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), mimetype='application/pdf')
    return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a font problem, as whatever font you need to display is not embeddable by reportlabs in the pdf.

Suggest you check the [reportlabs ftp server](http://www.reportlab.com/ftp/) for the font packages you need.

Comment: It's definitely the font lacking Chinese characters.

Comment: I'm confused as to how I should use the fonts. I see from the Pisa documentation that I can do it in the html template (which I have tried to no avail). And I'm not sure how I can do this with reportlab.